# Issues with seaborn clustering

Tags: python, cluster-computing, seaborn

Hi I have used seaborn before, but lately for somereason I can no longer use sns.clustermap. I have even gone back to the webpage and tried using their sample code pasted below, but I keep getting 'AttributeError: Unknown property axisbg  ' .
I have tried reinstalling Matplotlib and seaborn and even tried `conda install _library_Matplotlib` and `conda install _library_seaborn` , but nothing has worked. I even tried to change my python version.

python  version 3.6.6
matplotlib Version 3.0.2 
seaborn version 0.7.1

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
g = sns.clustermap(iris)
```

Error : 'AttributeError: Unknown property axisbg Figure size 720x720 with 0 Axes '

Comment: This is a compatibility problem between the matplotlib version (which is pretty new) and the seaborn version (which is rather old). You either need to update seaborn, or downgrade matplotlib. If using conda, updating seaborn should be as easy as `conda install seaborn==0.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working here, Spyder 3.3.1, Python 3.6.6, Qt 5.11.2, PyQt 5.11.3, Seaborn 0.9.0

Run:

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

Comment: Hi it partially worked but I then got a 'RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb'

Comment: Looks like versions of dependencies are in conflict, probably `numpy` or `pandas`. (Exactly)